# Is there away to add a button in using Google App Script, when you press a button?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to make a game in google sheets that can be played by giving the players access to the sheet.

Depending on the number of players, I've made it so there is a button that creates a sheet for each player in the game.

I would like a "Next Turn" button on each players individual screen.
Is it possible to have the function creating each of the new sheets, add in a button to do this?

The "Next Turn" Button is already made and works, but I can't get it into the other sheets.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: You might find it interesting to play around with the onSelectionChange(e) function.  You could us this function in rather unique ways to implement an interesting game by clicking on cell to use them a psuedo buttons.  The trigger is generated whenever a user changes the active range.

Comment: You could add a button to a sidebar via apps script which could function on the active sheet.